# React Failed to compile. Module not found: Can't resolve 'Main.css'

Tags: reactjs

To my React project I added "Main.css" file and I imported it in Navigation.js component. Unfortunately, I get this error "Failed to compile. ./src/components/Navigation.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'Main.css' in '/Users/monikastrzalka/Documents/INFORMATYKA/WEB DEVELOPMENT PROJECTS/PROJECT2/project2/src/components'". I have no idea why this is happening.That's the first time. Please help me. Below you will find necessary data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCcHL.png)

Comment: You are importing local file. Should be `'./Main.css'`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue lies in the import

```
import "./Main.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways import trys to find what you're indicating. Currently import is interpreting 'Main.css' as a full package - if there was a 'Main.css' library in your package.json and living in your node_modules folder import would be handling this correctly.

The other way to import is to identify a relative filepath. You can indicate the relative path the same way as your terminal.

If you try:

import "./Main.css"

import will know to look for a relative file pathway that exists inside your project.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue but created another error
ostcss!./src/components/Main.css)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/monikastrzalka/Desktop/PROJECT2/project2/src/components/Main.css'

Comment: that error message is stating that the file Main.css doesn't exist in that path.  Seems odd though as I see it exists in the components folder

Comment: delete your node_modules, reinstall packages and try running app again

Comment: @RobertTerrell Thank you very much for your help. Deleting node_modules and re-installation of packages solved the issue.